# How can I read a single byte from a binary stream?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have a binary file which I would like to process one byte at a time. This is what I have for reading the first character of the file:

```
ifstream file("input.dat", ios::binary);
unsigned char c;
file >> c;
```

However, when I step through this code with a debugger, `c` always has the value `0x00` although the first (and only) character of the file is `0x0A`. In fact, any other character is also totally ignored.

How do I read individual bytes from this file?

Comment: `0x0A` is the `'\n'` character, which is treated as whitespace 
 by `operator>>` and thus skipped from reading. That is why `c` ends up as `0x00`, because `operator>>` is not reading anything worth outputting.

Comment: But the file is opened as binary, so it should read every character, including whitespace. However, the strange thing is that after opening the file as binary, nothing works anymore. I tried using operator>>, file.read and file.get but all to no avail.

Comment: `ifstream file("input.dat", ios::binary);` -- There is no check to see if the file exists.  Thus this code is incomplete.  A tell-tale sign that there can be an issue with this is that the name that you are giving `ifstream` is not a full path, thus you're assuming the file opened successfully when it may not have.

Comment: @WaisKamal binary vs text mode only affects line-break conversions. It doesn't affect how `operator>>` handles whitespace. So, you simply can't read `0x0A` with `operator>>`, period. You need to use `get()` or `read()` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::istream::get` or `std::istream::read`.

```
char c;
if (!file.get(c)) { error }
```

```
int c = file.get();
if (c == EOF) { error }
```

```
char c;
if (!file.read(&c, 1)) { error }
```

And finally:

```
unsigned char c;
if (!file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c), 1)) { error }
```

Comment: I have to use unsigned char, but get only accepts a char.

Comment: sooooo `char c; file.get(c); unsigned char c2 = c;` ?

Comment: Is this guaranteed to preserve the MSB of the original char in the file? Also, will `static_cast` always work or do I have to `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: `Is this guaranteed to preserve the MSB of the original char in the file?` Uuuhm, while there is no technical  guarantee, there [does not exist](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2218.htm) a machine where it wouldn't. So, yes, the MSB value will be preserved, because it's twos complement and how a signed to unsinged values are converted. `Also, will static_cast always work` there is no static_cast in my code. `do I have to reinterpret_cast?` in case of `file.read` when passing something else then `char*`, then yes, `reinterpret_cast` is needed.

Comment: Strangely both read and get don't work for me. In both cases c stays at `0x00`.

Comment: @WaisKamal the only way that can happen is if the read is failing, ie because the file is not opened to begin with, or the read is reaching EOF.

Comment: Or the file actually contains 0x00. (or you are printing the value of c incorrectly, or..)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I just checked and it was indeed not opened. But this issue only exists if I use ios::binary; if I remove it the file opens normally.

Comment: @WaisKamal binary vs text mode doesn't affect whether the stream can open the file. It only affects how the data is interpreted after the file is opened.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I've got it to work by using `ios::binary | ios::in`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but just when I open it in binary and call `is_open()` it returns false.

Comment: @WaisKamal Specifying `ios::in` for `std::ifstream` is redundant, `ios::in` is already implied since `ifstream` is an input-only stream and will add `ios::in` to anything you specify. And again, `ios::binary` has no effect on opening the file. So, either you are misdiagnosing the issue, or your runtime is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the file exists. You do not check any error prior to reading from the stream. You could for instance:

```
ifstream file("input.dat", ios::binary);
if(!file.is_open())
{
  throw std::runtime_error("invalid path");
}
```

Comment: The file exists actually.

Comment: While this is important info, this doesn't actually try to answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::ifstream is("in.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (!is) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file!\n";
    }
    for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> beg(is), end; beg != end; ++beg) {
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```